# Ubuntu 12.10 live usb boot hangs at Splash screen

Tags: boot, 12.10, ati, plymouth

I have created Ubuntu 12.10-amd64 bootable usb disk.

It boots but when I select `Install on harddisk` or `Run without install`, it just stops at the splash screen.

I tried `-nomodeset`, but same thing happens. I removed `splash` from command line. The setup stops at `Stopping save kernel messages`.

Does this have to do anything with ATI graphics?

I've ATI 4000x series.

Comment: try `noacpi` or `acpi=off`(as a last resort). Also what are the messages before `Stopping save kernel messages`?